# Error when creating a MS Teams meeting using Microsoft Graph API in an ASP.NET Web API in C#

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently developing an ASP.NET Web API that will enable the creation of Teams meetings and the retrieval of the connection URL. I have followed Microsoft's documentation, but it seems incomplete, and I am encountering numerous errors.

I added an app registration in Azure with the API permissions `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All`. I should be able to create multiple links simultaneously without using a generic account. I simply want to authorize my resource to create meetings.

```
var tenantId = "...";
var clientId = "...";
var clientSecret = "...";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet.CreateOrGetPostRequestBody
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-02-20T14:30:00.2444915-07:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024-02-20T15:00:00.2464912-07:00"),
    Subject = "Test meeting from graph API",
    Participants = new MeetingParticipants
    {
        Organizer = new MeetingParticipantInfo
        {
            Identity = new IdentitySet
            {
                User = new Identity
                {
                    Id = "test@example.com"
                }
            },
            Upn = "test@example.com"
        },
        Attendees = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>
        {
            new MeetingParticipantInfo
            {
                Identity = new IdentitySet
                {
                    User = new Identity
                    {
                        Id = "test@example.com"
                    }
                },
                Upn = "test@example.com"
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = await graphClient.Users["test@example.com"].OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet.PostAsync(requestBody);
return result.JoinWebUrl;
```

When executing this code with the specified credentials from Azure, I am getting this error:

> Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError

with an http 404 error code

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>
> Library.Http.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Library.Abstractions.Serialization.ParsableFactory<Library.Abstractions.Serialization.IParsable>>, System.Diagnostics.Activity, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> Library.Http.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync(Library.Abstractions.RequestInformation, Library.Abstractions.Serialization.ParsableFactory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Library.Abstractions.Serialization.ParsableFactory<Library.Abstractions.Serialization.IParsable>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> Library.Http.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync(Library.Abstractions.RequestInformation, Library.Abstractions.Serialization.ParsableFactory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Library.Abstractions.Serialization.ParsableFactory<Library.Abstractions.Serialization.IParsable>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> Users.Item.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet.CreateOrGetRequestBuilder.PostAsync(Users.Item.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet.CreateOrGetPostRequestBody, System.Action<Library.Abstractions.RequestConfiguration<Library.Abstractions.DefaultQueryParameters>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken) in CreateOrGetRequestBuilder.cs
> App.Services.MeetingGeneratorService.CreateMeeting(App.Dto.v2.MeetingDto) in MeetingGeneratorService.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code `graphClient.Users["test@example.com"].OnlineMeetings`, it looks like you are trying to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) to create teams meeting. Then let's see the permission information in the API document, it indicates that `Application` type of permission is not supported, which means we aren't able to use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions) to generate access token（requires Application type of permission） then call this API. However, we can see that you are using client credential flow in your codes -> `var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential`

As a workaround, we can use [Calendar events API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) as to create online meetings which supports Application type of permission. Setting `IsOnlineMeeting = true` and adding Application type permission `Calendars.ReadWrite` are required. I [had a test before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68113245/14574199) to prove this API can solve your problem. Code snippet should look like below.

```
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 5.x
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var requestBody = new Event
{
    Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "Does next month work for you?",
    },
    Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
    {
        DateTime = "2019-03-10T12:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
    },
    End = new DateTimeTimeZone
    {
        DateTime = "2019-03-10T14:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
    },
    Location = new Location
    {
        DisplayName = "Harry's Bar",
    },
    Attendees = new List<Attendee>
    {
        new Attendee
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "adelev@contoso.com",
                Name = "Adele Vance",
            },
            Type = AttendeeType.Required,
        },
    },
    IsOnlineMeeting = true,
    OnlineMeetingProvider = OnlineMeetingProviderType.TeamsForBusiness,
};

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user_id}"].Events.PostAsync(requestBody);
```